# Changing -webkit-animation-play-state with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit-animation

Hi I have been trying to figure out how to change my css3 -webkit-animation-play-state from paused to running by clicking on another div. Does any one know how I would do this?? Im assuming I would need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're able to do it unless you use JavaScript.  Using JavaScript, you would have to fetch the `style.webkitAnimationPlayState` of the element you wish to change.  If it's an empty string, then it is set to the inital value, which is `"running"`.

In the example code, `clickDiv` is the div you click and `animationDiv` is the div whose `webkit-animation-play-state` is getting changed:

```
clickDiv.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (animationDiv.style.webkitAnimationPlayState == "paused") {
        animationDiv.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
    }else if(animationDiv.style.webkitAnimationPlayState == "running" || animationDiv.style.webkitAnimationPlayState == ""){
        animationDiv.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused"; // assuming you want to toggle
    }
    console.log(animationDiv.style.webkitAnimationPlayState);
})?
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/lq_blocco/JCzpd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

look at
http://jsfiddle.net/JCzpd/37/

```js
var animationDiv = document.getElementById("aD");
var clickDiv = document.getElementById("cD");
clickDiv.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (animationDiv.style.animation == "") {
animationDiv.style.animation = " anim .5s forwards";
//animationDiv.style.animation = " anim running  .1s infinite";
    }else{
animationDiv.style.animation = ""; // assuming you want to toggle
    }
});
```

```css
 #aD{ background-color:green;
 height:30px;
 margin:2px 0 5px 2px;}
 #cD{background-color:blue;}
@keyframes anim{
   0%{ background-color:green;}
  100%{ background-color:red;}
}
#aD:hover{animation: anim 1s infinite;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div id="aD">animated div</div>
<div id="cD">click div</div>
```

change commented line for different anim